# WCF web service web method called in single method?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am using following web service and getting following result in json format but i want result in another format mention in below. I want a result in combine format means result in single array or array list through my web service.
I am using 3 Methods
1. Login()
2. GetCetorgy()
3. GetSubCategory()

## I want all three method result in single method  in mentioned format.

```
 code Start
===========
public class LoginWebService : ILoginWebService
{
public bool Login(string uname, string pwd)
{
bool bresult;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
con.Open();
}
cmd.CommandText = "select * from UserList where UserName=@username and Password=@pwd";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = uname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pwd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pwd;
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read() == true)
{
bresult = true;
}
else
{
bresult = false;
}
con.Close();
return bresult;
}
public String[] GetCategory()
{
var names = new List<string>();
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
//SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123");
try
{
myConnection.Open();
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
myCommand.CommandText = "Select CategoryName from CategoryTG order by CategoryName ";
//myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameFilter);
SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
names.Add(myReader["CategoryName"].ToString());
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
myConnection.Close();
}
return names.ToArray();
}
public String[] GetSubCategory()
{
var names = new List<string>();
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
//SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123");
try
{
myConnection.Open();
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
myCommand.CommandText = "Select CategoryName,SubCategoryName from SubCategoryTG order by CategoryName ";
//myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameFilter);
SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
names.Add("Category: " + myReader["CategoryName"].ToString());
names.Add("SubCategory: " + myReader["SubCategoryName"].ToString());
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
myConnection.Close();
}
return names.ToArray();
}
}
Code End
=========

I am getting followung result from my service method
====================================================== 
1. Login   =   true

2. GetCategory =  [
"Eat",
"Entertainment",
"Hobbies",
"Sports"
]

3. GetSubCategory =[
"Category: Eat",
"SubCategory: Pubs",
"Category: Eat",
"SubCategory: Eat out ",
"Category: Entertainment",
"SubCategory: Dance",
"Category: Hobbies",
"SubCategory: Test",
"Category: Sports",
"SubCategory: Tennis",
"Category: Sports",
"SubCategory: Golf",
"Category: Sports",
"SubCategory: Soccer"
]

But  i want following result
============================== 

 {
"Login" "True"
"Categories" |
{
"Category" "Eat",
"Entertainment",
"Hobbies",
"Sports"
}
{"Category" "Eat"
"SubCategory"|
"Eat Out"
"Pubs"
}
{"Category" "Sports"
"SubCategory"|
"Tennis"
"Golf"
}
}
```

Comment: any one solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, This code violates the Single responsible principle. i.e your Login class should have a single purpose.(SOLID principle http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod).If you need maintainable and reliable code you need to refactor the above code according to SOLID Principles.

If you need to get this done as it is, then it is better to use Data Transfer Objects(DTO) and send them to client by using a json formatter. It is much cleaner and proper approach than manipulating the string lists.

This article explains how you can easily support different data and serialization formats in WCF

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Supporting-different-data-b0351c9a

Comment: can u please optimize my code. i am totally blank i can't under stand what  i do?